# Pattern matching with tag in Lua

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

I'm trying to parse a text, and based on tags to do actions.

The text is:

```xml
<window>
    <caption>My window
</window>
<panel>
    <label>
        <caption>
        <position>50,50
        <color>255,255,255
    </label>
</panel>
```

Code:

```
function parse_tag(chunck)
    for start_tag,tag_name in string.gfind(chunck,"(<(.-)>)") do
        if (child_obj[tag_name]) then
            print(start_tag)
            for data,end_tag in string.gfind(chunck,"<" .. tag_name ..">(.-)(</" .. tag_name ..">)") do
                for object_prop,value in string.gfind(data,"<(.-)>(.-)") do
                    print("setting property = \"" .. object_prop .. "\", value of" .. value);
                end
            end
            print("</" .. tag_name ..">");
        elseif(findInArray(main_obj,tag_name)) then
            print("Invalid data");
            stop();
        end
    end
end
for key,tag in ipairs(main_obj) do
    for start_tag,tag_name,chunck,end_tag in string.gfind(data,"(<(" .. tag.name .. ")>)(.-)(</" .. tag.name .. ">)") do --> searching for window/panel start and end tags
        if (findInArray(main_obj,tag_name)) then
            print(start_tag)
            parse_tag(chunck); --> parses the tag with child tag
            print(end_tag)
        end
    end
end
```

It seems to fail getting the value, as I get the following output:

```xml
<window>
</window>
<panel>
<label>
setting property = "caption", value of
setting property = "position", value of
setting property = "color", value of
</label>
</panel>
```

How can I use match the string after the first `<%tag%>` until the next `<%tag%>` or end of the chunk.

Comment: This generally seems to be a bad idea, why not use an XML parser?

Answer (score 1):

```
string.gfind(data,"<(.-)>(.-)")
```

Here, you try to match the value with `.-`. However, `-` is lazy, i.e, `.-` will try to match as little as possible, in this case, an empty string.

Try telling it to match until the next `<`:

```
string.gfind(data,"<(.-)>(._)<")
```

Comment: I'm trying to capture the string between <(.-)> and the next <(.-)>  or end of the file..
Using greedy modifier ignores the next <(.-)>

Comment: @user3185939 I don't know about `string.gfind` and your example is not minimal, I thought in the inner most loop, `data` contains just something like `<position>50,50`. Anyway, if the next `<` is still in `data`, try `"<(.-)>(._)<"`.

Comment: @user3185939 If that still doesn't work, create [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), 2 or 3 lines of code is enough to show the problem.

Comment: My bad, I will post next time more minimal example.

Answer (score 0):

Tried different type of captures.
This

```
string.gfind(data,"<(.-)>([^%<+.-%>+]+)")
```

Seems to work